# MySQL: Use a temporary table twice elegantly without WITH clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck on MySQL 5.7, which does not have the WITH clause. How can I elegantly achieve the following?

```sql
WITH
  cte AS (SELECT a, b, COUNT(*) AS num FROM t WHERE /* some condition on a */ GROUP BY a, b ORDER BY a, b)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE /* some condition on b */
UNION
SELECT a, 'AVG' as b, AVG(num) AS num FROM cte GROUP BY a;
```

Where `a` is datetime and `b` is string.

I know I can do what I want by just repeating the conditions in `cte` in the 2 `SELECT` statements below. But as I said, I would like to learn a more elegant solution.

Comment: MySQL supports [temporary tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) if you have sufficient privileges to use them.

Answer (score 0):

SQL isn't elegant, since you want your output to include the average then you need a union and since you need a union you need to parse the data twice AND manually calculate the avg PS you need an order by to place the AVG immediately after the num it applies to. for example given:-

```
+-------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| EmpID | ProdID | HireStartDt | HireEndDate |
+-------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| 98765 | X123   | 2020-08-01  | 2020-12-31  |
| 98765 | X123   | 2021-01-01  | 2021-12-31  |
| 98765 | X123   | 2022-01-01  | 2022-12-31  |
| 43567 | X123   | 2021-01-01  | 2021-12-31  |
| 43567 | X123   | 2022-01-29  | 2022-12-31  |
| 65427 | X123   | 2021-05-06  | 2021-08-28  |
| 65427 | X123   | 2022-03-01  | 2022-12-31  |
|     1 | X123   | 2020-08-01  | 2020-10-31  |
|     1 | X123   | 2021-01-01  | 2021-12-31  |
|     1 | X123   | 2022-01-01  | 2022-12-31  |
+-------+--------+-------------+-------------+
10 rows in set (0.010 sec)

SELECT empid, month(hirestartdt) mth, COUNT(*) AS num 
FROM t 
#WHERE empid = 1 
GROUP BY empid, month(hirestartdt) 
union all 
SELECT empid, 'AVG' as b, count(*)/ count(distinct month(hirestartdt)) AS num 
FROM t 
#where empid = 1
GROUP BY empid
order by empid,mth;

+-------+------+--------+
| empid | mth  | num    |
+-------+------+--------+
|     1 | 1    | 2.0000 |
|     1 | 8    | 1.0000 |
|     1 | AVG  | 1.5000 |
| 43567 | 1    | 2.0000 |
| 43567 | AVG  | 2.0000 |
| 65427 | 3    | 1.0000 |
| 65427 | 5    | 1.0000 |
| 65427 | AVG  | 1.0000 |
| 98765 | 1    | 2.0000 |
| 98765 | 8    | 1.0000 |
| 98765 | AVG  | 1.5000 |
+-------+------+--------+
11 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```